# HttpErrors PassThrough specific statuscode

Tags: http, iis, web-config

I Added this section to web.config, to show custom error for 500, and 404 errors.

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <clear/>
  <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/CustomError/ServerError" />
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/CustomError/NotFound" />
</httpErrors>
```

I want to set the status code manually for some pages to 423 'Business requirements', my question how can I pass through specific statuscode?

Thanks in advance.